# Trying to use clone - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Suppose I have an `ajax` request sending me a callback data `data` (some text). I have in my `html`

```
<tbody class="files-upload">
                        </tbody>
...some tags
<tr class="clonable template-upload">
    <td>
        <span class="preview-upload"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and

```
 var clone = $('.clonable').clone();
  $(clone).find(".preview-upload").text(data);
  $('tbody.files-upload').append($(clone));
```

The problem is that my `.files-upload` remains empty !

Comment: Are there any problems in your Javascript console?

Comment: I know this may seem like a silly question, but is your javascript code inside your callback function?

Comment: As a suggestion, I would not mix single and double quotes in your code. It's only a readability issue, but if you work with other developers it may drive them crazy. Also, `clone` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to keep wrapping it in the jQuery core.

Comment: are you wrapping what you have provided as html in an `table` element? Here's a fiddle that works if it is: http://jsfiddle.net/XAYWd/

Comment: @NeilS right I didn't know about it !! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to wrap your table tags by a `table` tag. I guess it is the reason why `console.log($(clone).find(".preview-upload").length);` outputs to `0`

Comment: Amazing that you guessed at that, why didn't the OP have table tags?

Comment: @BjornTipling in fact the OP edited his post to say that the table related tags where not displaying, but then he deleted his update ;)

Answer (score 1):

The case is probably that your jQuery select statement isn't finding your `.preview-upload`. I bet if you did this:

```
console.log($(clone).find(".preview-upload").length);
```

That it would show you `0`. Use the web inspector or firebug to improve your query. A query with 0 found elements is a noop. It will not tell you that it did not add any text nodes, it simply does nothing.

I always do this anyway, but it probably doesn't help with your problem:

```
$('.preview-upload', clone).text(data);
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: in fact I want to add my data with the ajax callback function, so it is not simple to provide jsfiddle

Comment: The ajax part doesn't matter. If you try this without the ajax it should have the same problem.

Comment: In fact I have just noticed some weird thing  : in my console, I can only see `<span class="preview-upload"></span>` but not the table tags that wrapps it !!!

Comment: Table elements are weird and not very responsive to dynamic JavaScript updates. Best to create and delete entire tables than to try and show or hide individual elements within the table. I've had success with removing elements, but adding them can be challenging depending on what browsers you want to support.